# bokeh Hovertool tooltips showing date as number

Tags: pandas, bokeh

After making some transformations to a csv, I have a dataframe:

```
ENTRYDATE |  TRANSACTIONS
2017/05/01     5
2017/05/02     20
..
2018/02/05     15
```

I converted it to datetime in pandas  and create a lineplot with tooltips with

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,DatetimeTickFormatter, NumeralTickFormatter, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\file.csv')    
df2=df[['ENTRYDATE']] 
df2['ENTRYDATE']=pd.to_datetime(df2['ENTRYDATE'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df2=(df2.groupby([df2['ENTRYDATE'].dt.date]).size().reset_index(name='Transactions'))
#print(df2)
#print(df2.info())

source=ColumnDataSource(data=df2)

#hovertool

p=figure(plot_width=800,plot_height=500)

hover=HoverTool(tooltips=[("Date","@ENTRYDATE"),("Transactions","@Transactions")],
formatters={"ENTRYDATE":"datetime"},
mode='vline')
p.add_tools(hover)

p.scatter(x="ENTRYDATE",y="Transactions",color='blue', source=source)
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter()
p.yaxis.formatter=NumeralTickFormatter(format="0")

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

For some reason, the tooltip displaying the ENTRYDATE does not actually show the date (i.e. `2017-05-01`), rather it shows a some long number (i.e. `14962752000000`). Can someone tell me how to edit this so that the tooltips show the date in a date format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell it the *CDS column name* in the `formatters` dict, and also need to specify the actual specific datetime format you want for the field, e.g.

```
HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("Date", "@ENTRYDATE{%F}"),  # must specify desired format here
    ("Transactions", "@Transactions")
], formatters={"@ENTRYDATE":"datetime"}, mode='vline')
```

Comment: do you mean `source=ColumnDataSource(data=df2,formatters={"ENTRYDATE":"datetime"})`? For that I got `unexpected attribute 'formatters'`

Comment: No, I mean replace the value of `formatters` exactly where you have it in the code you posted above.

Comment: I have it like so now `hover=HoverTool(tooltips=[("Date","@ENTRYDATE"),("Transactions","@Transactions")],
formatters={"ENTRYDATE":"datetime"},
mode='vline')` but it yields the same result

Comment: Can you update your code above to be complete and current so it can be easily run? Also you should *always* state version information in any question.

Comment: i put the full code in the initial post. The dataframe comes from a csv. The objective is the count the dates and plot them by date. `bokeh==0.12.7, pandas==0.22.0`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh,  you need to also specify the date time format you actually want, answer updated

Comment: This works for me with bokeh v1.4. But since 2.0, it shows a screwed percentage number. Do you know what to do since v2?

Comment: format specifiers require the leading `@` or `$` on the field since 2.0 as described in the release notes https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#hovertool-formatters-specification

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method is to convert the dates to strings as a separate column.  Getting some stock data from Yahoo. I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd

# use bp as bokeh plot
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource


# get the datetime library for date & time calcs
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = pd.read_csv("DJI.csv")

data.head()
```

The initial data frame looks like the image below.
[image]

Then do the following for plotting:

```
# clean up the date fields to become dates

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# create a string column for plotting
data["DateString"] = data["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# work on the bokeh plot
# set the data source for the plots and hover tool
cds = ColumnDataSource(data)

bp = figure(width=500, height=250, x_axis_type="datetime", sizing_mode="scale_width")
# bp.x_range = Range1d(bounds=(2015-12-31, 2018-12-28))

# make the hover tool and add it
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [("Date","@DateString"),("Close", "@Close")])
bp.add_tools(hover)

bp.line("Date", "Close", color = "Red", alpha = 0.5, source = cds)

output_file("Timeseries.html")
show(bp)
```

[image]